# How to get gradient for calculating gradient penalty loss in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

I am using a custom loss function that calculates gradient penalty loss in a Keras functional model. In the loss function I need to calculate gradients. This is the function I am using:

```py
def gradient_penalty_loss(self, y_true, y_pred, averaged_samples):
        """
        Computes gradient penalty based on prediction and weighted real / fake samples
        """
        gradients = K.gradients(y_pred, averaged_samples)[0]
        # compute the euclidean norm by squaring ...
        gradients_sqr = K.square(gradients)
        #   ... summing over the rows ...
        gradients_sqr_sum = K.sum(gradients_sqr, axis=np.arange(1, len(gradients_sqr.shape)))
        #   ... and sqrt
        gradient_l2_norm = K.sqrt(gradients_sqr_sum)
        # compute lambda * (1 - ||grad||)^2 still for each single sample
        gradient_penalty = K.square(1 - gradient_l2_norm)
        # return the mean as loss over all the batch samples
        return K.mean(gradient_penalty)
```

But this gives me following error:

```
TypeError: in user code:

    File "..../miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1338, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "..../StarGAN-Keras/StarGAN.py", line 162, in gradient_penalty_loss  *
        gradients = K.gradients(y_pred, averaged_samples)[0]
    File "..../miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend.py", line 4695, in gradients  **
        return tf.compat.v1.gradients(
    File "..../miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/keras_tensor.py", line 285, in __array__
        raise TypeError(

    TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(4, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.__operators__.add/AddV2:0', description="created by layer 'tf.__operators__.add'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

I have tried using `tf.GradientTape()`, changing the function to the following according to [`this code on github`](https://github.com/timsainb/tensorflow2-generative-models/blob/master/3.0-WGAN-GP-fashion-mnist.ipynb):

```py
def gradient_penalty_loss(self, y_true, y_pred, averaged_samples):
        """
        Computes gradient penalty based on prediction and weighted real / fake samples
        """
        averaged_samples = tf.Variable(averaged_samples)
        with tf.GradientTape() as t:
            t.watch(averaged_samples)
            d_hat = self.discriminate(averaged_samples)
        gradients = t.gradient(d_hat, averaged_samples)
        ddx = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(gradients ** 2, axis=[1, 2]))
        d_regularizer = tf.reduce_mean((ddx - 1.0) ** 2)
        return d_regularizer
```

But it still gives the same error:

```
TypeError: in user code:

    File "..../miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1338, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "..../StarGAN-Keras/StarGAN.py", line 162, in gradient_penalty_loss  *
        averaged_samples = tf.Variable(averaged_samples)
    File "/home/shafquat/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/keras_tensor.py", line 285, in __array__
        raise TypeError(

    TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(4, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.__operators__.add/AddV2:0', description="created by layer 'tf.__operators__.add'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

So how can I calculate the gradients for my gradient penalty loss calculation since it's saying I can't use gradient tapes?